# Does Azure Text to Speech API support <mark> tags?

Tags: azure, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services, ssml

Does Azure Text to Speech API support  tags as part of its support for SSML 1.0? How can I make a call to get the timestamps of marker positions? By default, it just returns the audio file output.

I have searched everywhere, but I was not able to find any endpoint or info on this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `<mark>` tag is not currently supported.

However, we do support word boundary events now; an example can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/csharp/sharedcontent/console/speech_synthesis_samples.cs).

Comment: How to use the word boundary in curl or in PHP? is there any examples?

Answer (score 0):

No, Based on [Azure TTS API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-text-to-speech#convert-text-to-speech) , it just reply an audio file as a response:

[image]

If you have custom requirements, maybe separating your sentences into multiple calls would be a workaround.

Comment: Yes, I read this before. However, while googling found out constants defined for <mark> tags in .net SDK so I was doubting if it is supported and if I missed out any other endpoint.  You are right. Its not supported yet.  Here are the comments from product team

Comment: Hi,

Currently it's not supported. We have forwarded this feedback to Product team. You can raise a user voice request here so the community can vote and provide their feedback, the product team then checks this feedback and implements in future releases.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<mark>`, you may use `<bookmark>`, which seems to have the same usage:
Cf the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-synthesis-markup?tabs=python#bookmark-element